# Cardinality of plaint text - hashed text

Tags: hash, bcrypt

I was wondering if it's theorically possible that **2 different plain Strings** result to **the same hashed String**, For example using Bcrypt algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are an infinite number of possible inputs ("plain strings" in your case), assuming any length is permitted, and only a finite number of hashes because hashes have a fixed length. When two different inputs result in the same hash, this is known as a collision. [This article](https://learncryptography.com/hash-functions/hash-collision-attack) explains the significance in terms of cryptography